# Make block element insert itself between text

Tags: css, css-float

I want to have this markup

```
<p> Content 1 </p>
<p> Content 2 </p>
<div> Div 1 </div>
```

And I want it to display like this:

```
<p> Content 1 </p>
<div> Div 1 </div>
<p> Content 2 </p>
```

The reason for this is that I want the text for the page (those in `<p>` tags) be edited in one richtext editor and then the contents in the `<div>` tag be edited in a separate section but the contents of the `<div>` tag will still be centered within the content of the page.

I am currently thinking of doing this in PHP where I will simply `explode()` it, splitting it by sentences and then displaying the first few sentences before the `div` and the remaining sentences after the `div`. But I was hoping that there would be some "`float`"-like css trick to this problem.

For reference of what I really want to do, please take a look at this site:

http://katron.sourcefit.com/static/a&a/about-us.html

Comment: If you know the height of the `div` i.e. it is going to remain constant. You could position the second `<p>` absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your div inline instead of block:

```
<div style="display: inline;"></div>
```

That way it will act like a `<span>` but still be a div.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some `absolute positioning`.

```
<p id="Content1"> Content 1 </p>
<p id="Content2"> Content 2 </p>
<div id="Div1"> Div 1 </div>
```

CSS

```
#Content1{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background:pink;
}

#Content2{
    position:absolute;
    top:120px;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}

#Div1{
    position:absolute;
    top:60px;    
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    background:green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/bQLuH/

Comment: Thanks @Anthony. For sure it has its limitations.